# Angular and typescript 5.2

Tags: angular, typescript

If I try to install updates for packages in my angular project, then I got some dependency errors:

```
project/path$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.5
npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.2.2
...
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer typescript@">=4.9.3 <5.2" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
```

That means I need TypeScript version below 5.2 e.g. 5.1.1.

project/package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.2.8",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.18",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.1",
    ...
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
}
```

I don't know if modify the version in package.json is a good idea because other packages could depend on the 5.2.2 version. How to resolve the dependency issue, I mean how to downgrade packages in package.json programmatically, so that all packages work with latest angular version? Or in general how to install an up to date [angular environment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli)?

What I tried: I deleted my `project/node_modules` folder and `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`, then:

```
$ npm install -g @angular/cli
$ ng version
Angular CLI: 16.2.5
Node: 18.16.0
Package Manager: npm 9.5.1
OS: linux x64

Angular: <error>
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, fire
... forms, localize, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.5 (cli-only)
@nguniversal/builders           <error>
@nguniversal/express-engine     <error>
@schematics/angular             16.2.5 (cli-only)
rxjs                            7.8.1 (cli-only)
typescript                      <error>
zone.js                         <error>


$ npm list -g --depth 0
/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib
├── @angular/cli@16.2.5
├── corepack@0.17.0
├── firebase-tools@12.4.4
├── npm@9.5.1
└── serverless@3.35.2
```

If I run now `project/path$ npm install`, then it throws same error that is described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TS 5.2 support will land with Angular v17 (early november).

Comment: Set typescript to 5.1.1 and run `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` to resolve the issue?

Comment: You shouldn’t do that outside of official support.